# Error in Library System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that collects events from Event Hubs and pushes to CosmosDB

```html
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("transacciones", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            var client = new CosmosClient(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDBConnection"),
                new CosmosClientOptions()
                {
                    SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                    {
                        IgnoreNullValues = true
                    }
                }); ;
            
            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {

                    byte[] eventBytes = eventData.Body.ToArray();
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventBytes);

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

        }
```

When I run the code I always get an error precisely where the connection to ComosDB is created

[image]

I have tried to solve the problem by installing the library, as well as Microsoft.Entensions.Configuration without success. Reading in forums I found out that this library is obsolete for Core 3.1

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please do not create clients inside the `Run` Function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3.1 is no longer a supported runtime; it reached end-of-support on December 13, 2022.  *([support policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core))*

You'll need to update the target framework for your application to `net6` or `net7`.